# jQuery UI autocomplete with pre-transformed json url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Ok so I understand that jQueryUI expect the object in key/value form with the key's "value" and "label" so I've already transformed my data into a this json format. Now I'm just not sure how the easiest way to source my json url. All of the other articles on this matter show a need to pull the data in and transform it which isn't my case.

My json file at **getuser.php?name=brian**

```
[
   {"label":"Brian Aa","value":"7e36e"},
   {"label":"Brian Ba","value":"3e497"},
   {"label":"Brian Bc","value":"c3263"},
   {"label":"Brian Cc","value":"5be94"}
]
```

My Autocomplete JS:

```
$("#test").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    "sample.com/getusers.php?name="+$("#test").val(), request, response;
  },
  minLength:2
});
```

And HTML

```
<div>
  <label for="tags">Requested By: </label>
  <input id="test">
</div>
```

Right now I'm getting nothing when I type, assuming I have to setup ajax but I thought I had seen an example of a pretty simple solution when the JSON is already formatted but cant seem to find it.

Comment: What do you mean by you need to "source your JSON URL"?

Comment: I have a page (getuser.php) that if you provide a parameter (?name=brian)  in the url it will provide json formatted data like the json dump ive shown in my question

Comment: Maybe I'm lacking sleep, but I still don't know what you mean. Are you saying you want to use a json array as the object's  "source" property? The very first example [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) shows them using an array..

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)...."An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]" - this is the format of my json that I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

The source function is not right, you need to get data from server and use response as call, see [Autocomplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
  source: function(request, response) {
     var url = "sample.com/getusers.php?name="+$("#test").val();
     $.get(url).done(function(data){
       response(data);
     }).fail(function(error){
        //dosomething here
     });
  }
```

Comment: That's not true. The first example on that page uses an array instead of an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of doing an ajax call, I just thought there was a more simple way.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax( {
        url: "sample/getusers.php?name="+$("#test").val(),
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
          response( data );
        }
      } );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    }
  } );
} );
```